# Puma server log error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, puma

I have an AngularJS web application sending requests to a Rails API running in a Puma server.

I see this error in my puma error log once or twice a day:

```
2015-02-26 23:26:41 +0000: HTTP parse error, malformed request (): #<Puma::HttpParserError: Invalid HTTP format, parsing fails.>
2015-02-26 23:26:41 +0000: ENV: {"rack.version"=>[1, 2], "rack.errors"=>#<File:/home/ubuntu/env/production/www/yanpyapi/log/puma.stderr.log>, "rack.multithread"=>true, "rack.multiprocess"=>false, "rack.run_once"=>false, "SCRIPT_NAME"=>"", "CONTENT_TYPE"=>"text/plain", "QUERY_STRING"=>"", "SERVER_PROTOCOL"=>"HTTP/1.1", "SERVER_SOFTWARE"=>"2.10.1", "GATEWAY_INTERFACE"=>"CGI/1.2"}
```

I guess I have something wrong in my code. Not sure. Any way to identify where?

Comment: What request are you making from your `AngularJS` app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any way to identify where?

Fork `puma` repository and add additional logging to [methods called](https://github.com/puma/puma/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=parse_error) `parse_error` (try to log all request body). Use this way you can find request which caused your problem and investigate it.

Comment: Nothing a bit simpler?

Comment: No :) As you can see in code, Puma doesn't provide any additional logging which can help to investigate your problem.

Answer (score 4):

it could be that you use somewhere ssl. in my example I used http://host.com(unsecure) and wss(secure) and it gave me that error. when they both match there is no error. so change it to http and ws or https and wss. Hope this is your case.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this is not my case. I´m not using SSL anywhere.